# How to insert line breaks dbunit dataset

Tags: xml, dataset, dbunit

How to insert line break in dbunit dataset? Like this:

```
    <user id="1" 
story="first line
       second line
       third line"/>
```

If I do it in this way field *story* in db appears divided by spaces only but I need a line break.

Answer (score 7):

Upps, I found solution:

```
<user id="1" 
story="first line&#13;&#10;second line&#13;&#10;third line"/>
```